# Change labels using language drop down in extjs application

Tags: extjs

I would like to know is there any functionality through which we can provide a provision to the user to that it can select a language from the drop-down and the whole application labels got converted into the selected language.

For example, on a page, we have a combo box with values English & Dutch. By default, when application load then I am able to fetch browser's language and show application labels in the same. But I want to know, how a user can manually convert an Ext JS application into the desired language.

I have tried google translator but UI not rendered as expected.

Comment: Have you considered backend logic in this task or do you want to achieve this only on UI ?

Comment: you can achieve this via localization. check this out https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?64225-Localization-with-Extjs!

Comment: @Tejas using back-end how can I achieve this, can you please help me out with an example?

Comment: Broad overview: Just read UI labels from backend, and backend will read labels from some x file. This x file is for eng labels. Now as alternate approach you can load these label file from UI also depending on browser language. Just see which approach you feel which fits in your application.

Comment: @Tejas Thanks for your idea. My approach is as follows:
I am getting a JSON structure for all the labels based on my language key viz. 'nl' or 'en' from back-end and then using ViewModel for updating the labels throughout the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach for the case is:
I am getting a JSON structure for all the labels based on my language key viz. 'nl' or 'en' from the back-end and then using ViewModel for updating the labels throughout the application.
This method turned out to be the pretty easy and appropriate method. I am able to change the labels without refreshing my application.